# How do I create a URL to link between apps in Padrino?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

I have a separate app called "api" that I'd like to link to from my admin app.  But if I do a link like:

```
%td=button_to "API", url("/api/users", :attributes, :id => user.id), 
  :method => :get, :class => :button_to
```

It takes me to /admin/api/users, I want to go to api/users/attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand but if you are in App2 and you want to render a link from another app you can: `Api.url(:users, :attributes, :id => user.id)`